# Include PHP inside JavaScript (.js) files

Tags: php, javascript

I have a JavaScript file (extension `.js`, not `.html`) containing several JavaScript functions.

I want to call one of the PHP functions in a PHP file containing only several PHP functions from within one of the JavaScript functions.

- Is that possible?
- Would I need to "include" the `.php` file containing the PHP function in the `.js` file?
- How would I do that? 
   For example, say I had a file called myLib.php containing a function called `myFunc` that takes two parameters (`param1` and `param2`). Then I have a `.js` file containing a function called `myJsFunc`.  How would a call the `myFunc` (PHP) from within the `myJsFunc` (JavaScript function)?  Wouldn't I need to include the PHP file somehow in the `.js` file?

Comment: This is *way too vague*. Please tell us what those functions do.

Comment: JavaScript executes on the user's browser. PHP executes on the server. Their functions cannot call each other. You need to understand the lifecycle of how PHP creates a web page including any JavaScript source code inside that page, and then JS starts running in the browser long after PHP has finished. Then if you really need to have the client and server talk to each other, look at XMLHttpRequest (AJAX et al).

Comment: *(tipp)* [Client-side Versus Server-side Coding - Part 1](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/923111/Client-side-Versus-Server-side-Coding---Part-1.htm)

Comment: I am basically doing AJAX.  Effectively, I am constructing a url in a JS function that calls the PHP via a XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### 7 years later update: This is terrible advice. Please don't do this.

If you just need to pass variables from PHP to the javascript, you can have a  tag in the php/html file using the javascript to begin with.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var phpVars = <?php echo json_encode($vars) ?>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourScriptThatUsesPHPVars.js"></script>
```

If you're trying to call functions, then you can do this like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="YourFunctions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // assume each element of $arrayWithVars has already been json_encoded
    functionOne(<?php echo implode(', ', $arrayWithVars); ?>);

    functionTwo(<?php echo json_encode($moreVars) ?>, <?php echo json_encode($evenMoreVars) ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: It's been nearly 6 years, and this still gets upvoted occasionally. This is absolutely terrible advice. You should strongly consider *why* you're needing to do this, and consider an alternative structure. If these variables can change over time, perhaps make an AJAX endpoint which represents what you need. If they really only matter at the time of the request, at least make a `<meta>` tag for each of the variables and read that, rather than generating JavaScript with PHP spitting into it.

Comment: it's utterly pointless and injection prone as well. `phpvars = <?php echo json_encode($vars); ?>;` is guaranteed to produce syntactically correct JS, whereas the above will kill the entire script block if there's a single `'` or other JS meta-char anywhere in the inserted text.

Comment: upvoted, just to bug you :P - since it is a highly upvoted answer maybe make the alternative (better solution) part of the answer instead of just a comment?

Comment: Sure it's not great architecturally, but for beginners needing a quick and dirty method it works fine. I've added `json_encode()` to the answer to make it a little safer.

Answer (score 25):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js

AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js

<FilesMatch "\.(js|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Add the above code in .htaccess file and run php inside js files

**DANGER:** This will allow the client to potentially see the contents of your PHP files. Do not use this approach if your PHP contains any sensitive information (which it typically does).

If you MUST use PHP to generate your JavaScript files, then please use pure PHP to generate the entire JS file.  You can do this by using a normal .PHP file in exactly the same way you would normally output html, the difference is setting the correct header using PHP's header function, so that the correct mime type is returned to the browser.  The mime type for JS is typically "***application/javascript***"

Comment: Now the php pages get downloaded on access

Comment: Can you explain how this "will allow the client to potentially see the contents of your PHP file"

Answer (score 11):

PHP and JS are not compatible; you may not simply include a PHP function in JS. What you probably want to do is to issue an [AJAX](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28Programmierung%29) Request from JavaScript and send a [JSON](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation) response using PHP.

Comment: +1 You don't even need a JSON response, it can really be anything; as long as you can parse/use it with JS in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 9):

A slightly modified version based on Blorgbeard one, for easily referenceable associative php arrays to javascript object literals:

### PHP File (*.php)

First define an array with the values to be used into javascript files:

```
<?php
$phpToJsVars = [
  'value1' => 'foo1',
  'value2' => 'foo2'    
];
?>
```

Now write the php array values into a javascript object literal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var phpVars = { 
<?php 
  foreach ($phpToJsVars as $key => $value) {
    echo '  ' . $key . ': ' . '"' . $value . '",' . "\n";  
  }
?>
};
</script>
```

### Javascript file (*.js)

Now we can access the javscript object literal from any other .js file with the notation:

```
phpVars["value1"]
phpVars["value2"]
```

Comment: Why is this better than `json_encode($phpToJsVars)`?

Answer (score 7):

This is somewhat tricky since PHP gets evaluated server-side and javascript gets evaluated client side.

I would call your PHP file using an AJAX call from inside javascript and then use JS to insert the returned HTML somewhere on your page.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the best way to accomplish this is to write the javascript in a .php and use jquery in a separate file to use the Jquery get script file or jquery load use php include function in the doc where the javascript will live.  Essentially this is how it will look.

Dynamic Javascript File in a .php file extension - Contains a mixture of php variables pre processed by the server and the javascript that needs these variables in scripts.

Static Js File - Using http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ or http://api.jquery.com/load/

In the main html page call the static file as a regular js file.  Calling the static js file will force load the dynamic data from the server.

**some file.php 1:**

```
<?php
$somevar = "Some Dynamic Data";
?>

$('input').val(<?php echo $somevar?>);
```

or simply echo the script such as

```
echo "$('input').val(".$somevar.");";
```

**File 2:somejsfile.js:**

```
$("#result").load( "file.php" );
```

**File 3 myhtml.html:**

```
<script src="somejsfile.js"></script>
```

I believe this answer the question for many people looking to mix php and javascript.  It would be nice to have that data process in the background then have the user have delays waiting for data.  You could also bypass the second file and simply use php's include on the main html page, you would just have your javascript exposed on the main page.  For performance that is up to you and how you want to handle all of that.

Answer (score 2):

**There is not any safe way to include `php` file into `js`**.

One thing you can do as **`define`** your php file data as **`javascript global variable`** in php file. for example i have three variable which i want to use as js.

abc.php

```
<?php
$abc = "Abc";
$number = 052;
$mydata = array("val1","val2","val3");
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var abc = '<?php echo $abc?>';
var number = '<?php echo $number ?>';
var mydata = <?php echo json_encode($mydata); ?>;
</script>
```

After **`use`** it directly in your **`js file`** wherever you want to use.

abc.js

```
function test(){
   alert('Print php variable : '+ abc +', '+number); 
}

function printArrVar(){
  alert('print php array variable : '+ JSON.stringify(mydata)); 
}
```

Beside If you have any critical data which you don't want to show publicly then you can encrypt data with js. and also get original value of it's from js so no one can get it's original value. if they show into publicly.

this is the standard way you can call php script data into js file without including js into php code or php script into js.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of messing with generic php-handlers do a 1-file exception using a rewrite:

Rename the .js-file to .php and rewrite the request to make it responde to a .js request. If the file is served by apache; add in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule myjsfile\.js myjsfile.php [L]
```

Secondly make the .php-file pretend to be a js-file. Inside the php-file start the file with:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/javascript'); ?>
```

Et voilà, you can now use php-tags in your ".js"-file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't include server side PHP in your client side javascript, you will have to port it over to javascript. If you wish, you can use [php.js](http://phpjs.org/), which ports all PHP functions over to javascript. You can also create a new php file that returns the results of calling your PHP function, and then call that file using AJAX to get the results.

Comment: Using [Uniter](http://github.com/asmblah/uniter) along with [php.js](http://locutus.io/php/) would allow the OP to run his php files directly from within his JS environment

Answer (score 1):

Because the Javascript executes in the browser, on the client side, and PHP on the server side, what you need is [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) - in essence, your script makes an HTTP request to a PHP script, passing any required parameters. The script calls your function, and outputs the result, which ultimately gets picked up by the Ajax call. Generally, you don't do this synchronously (waiting for the result) - the 'A' in AJAX stands for asynchronous!

Comment: Right...this is what I am doing.  I am constructing the a URL calling a php function inside the javascript function that uses XMLHttpRequest.  The question is can I call a php function inside of an included .php file or do I have to isolate the PHP code in a single file that contains the straight PHP code (no function) that the js code calls directly.  I just don't want to have a bunch of PHP files with code in them sitting around.  I'd like to incorporate the code in PHP functions in a .php file.

Comment: You could have all your functions in a single file then create a .php file that only has the include line to your functions file and a call to that function.

Comment: @GregH What you want is to have an API that your JS function can call (via AJAX or what not), specifying functions and arguments. This API could be in a single file or multiple, it depends on what you want.

Comment: Once you use AJAX to call the .php script on your server you can do anything in your .php script that you would normally do. There is no difference. It sounds like that is what is mixing you up. You can include any other script in the execution that you need to.

Comment: Also you can include arguments via post or get to specify what files you need to include in the .php function to only pull what you need.

Comment: Of course what @John said about specifying includes needs to be properly sanitized.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a double resolution of file:
"filename.php.js" in this way.
PHP generates JS in this file.
I got all parameters from DB.
This worked for me on xampp.