# After user login, js file to include php

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include PHP inside javascript (.js) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-file)

I have been searching for a while, which I could seems to find any valid answer to my case.

I currently have a header.js file (which is my header file), inside I got a word "login" which will be linked to login.php for user to login. Now after the user have successful login to my website, how would I go and change the word "login" inside the header.js file into something else? (For example, Hello "User name" so user knows they are logged in) How do I use php in js file or even call a php file inside js? Is there a better way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client, PHP runs on the server. Two different universes. You can change text on the page directly using Javascript, but when you serve up a NEW page from the server, you'd use PHP to insert the value into the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also do it via Ajax:

```
var linkName;
$.ajax({
    url: "check_login.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){
        if(json.data != '')
            linkName = "Welcome!";
        else
            linkName = "<a href='#'>Login</a>";
    }
});
```

in the check_login.php file you can do a check to see if the user is logged in or not and return the result as a json encoded array by echoing json_encode($results);

you could also return the username of the user and append it to your linkName at that point.

```
var linkName = "Welcome!"+json.data.username;
```

**Response:**  ("Can you show me some ample code of check_login.php file?")

Ya, is there a specific aspect of the file you would like to have demonstrated? The logic within this file would depend on how you are setting your user login status, if you are using sessions it could look something like this:

```
<?php
$user = Array();
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
    $user['logged'] = 'true';
    $user['name'] = 'James';
}

echo json_encode($user);
?>
```

Comment: Can you show me some ample code of check_login.php file?

Answer (score 1):

Name it header.php or header.js.php 
Now inside header.js.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<script type='text/javascript' language='Javascript'>
<?php
 if($_SESSION['loggedIn']){
?>
    document.write('Hello <?=$VrUserName?>');
<?php
} else{
?>
 document.write('<a href="/login.php">login</a>');
<?php
}
?>
</script>
```

Another way (this will allow header.js to be cached by browser as .php files are not cached)
Make login text a js variable in header.js
assign this variable in a php generated js code(as explained above) in a file included before header.js.