# Hide id from url

Tags: php, html

I want to pass an id from one page to another when user clicks a url. There can be multiple url each corresponding to a separate id. Based on url clicked, I want to pass corresponding id and an action. Currently I am using following approach:

```
<a href="Process.php?action=del&id='.$id.'">
```

However both action and id are visible in url. Is there any way to hide this information in url and not passing it through url?
Also if I pass them using hidden fields, they can be accessed using browser dev tools. I want to make them secure so they can't be read or modified at all.
I would like to hide this for security purpose so no any user can see this

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? Just to make it pretty?  Use meaningful names and url rewriting

Comment: why do you want to hide it..for security purpose?

Comment: Is it ok if you show encrypted data on the URL ?

Answer (score 3):

In HTML only, you'll not able to pass "hidden" variables through `$_GET`.

If you really want to hide some variables when a user click on a link, you can use Javascript with an auto-submitted form to use `$_POST` variables.

Example

```
<form method="POST" action="yourpage.php" id="yourform" style="display:none;">
   <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield" value="__" />
</form>

<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('yourform').submit();return false;" />
```

Now, in `yourpage.php`, you'll be able to obtain the `$_POST['hiddenfield']` value.

**Edit**:

I don't think it can be possible to really hide the values from dev tools. Btw, you can maybe use sessions, it will be more "secure"..

Example:

```
// page1.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['yourname'] = 'yourvalue';

// page2.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['yourname'];  // Contains 'yourvalue'
```

Comment: Just to be clear, they aren't hidden using a post, they just don't show up in the url. Anyone can view what was posted with browser dev tools

Comment: I know, only sessions would be more hidden.. But I understood that he just wants to not show the data in the URL.

Comment: Hashing the values would also be more secure, but that's a bit of extra work on the target page to get the actual values back from the hashes

Comment: Check my solution. I think that encrypting it with m_crypt is best solution. More in my answer post.

Comment: @Valentin : Neither I want to show them in URL nor they should be accessible using browser dev tools. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Valentin: How will you be able to decide, which particular url did user click and then based on that set the session value for field id?

Comment: It depends on your code. Btw, you can add a JS form and some PHP code in JS, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-file).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to hide id(if you mean security) is to encrypt it. You should use [MCRYPT](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) function to encrypt the id. You can encrypt both **ID** and your **ACTION** in one string and just pass this string to URL and then when you want to use it you can decrypt parameter and split it. When you connect it with **MOD_REWRITE** in htaccess you can get url like:

```
<a href="Process,Some title of yourpage,í,eHGxC•z»@”“§``"> to make it more "pretty" you can use base64 on this string.
```

or with base64, mcrypt and mod_rewrite

```
<a href="Process,SWRlYW">
```

to decrypt string you should use **base64_decode()**, **mcrypt_decrypt()**

Answer (score -1):

You can use base64 for this (if security is really a big concern). Before passing it to the URL,
you can encode it first and then in the receiving end, you can decode it.

Check this URL : http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

EDIT:

**Please ignore the line above in the bracket.**

Based on the comments below, base64 is really not responsible for security. Better approach is to use a server sided language to encrypt/decrypt values. Using base64 through javascript is not a good idea. Thanks Bobby.

Comment: "You can use base64 for this if security is really a big concern." I...I...I don't even...what the...?!

Comment: base64 gives no security it's very easy to decode and to guess that it's base64

Comment: "Base64 encoding" and "because security is needed" in the same sentence is like "I lock my front door" and "there's a key at the doorstep" in the same sentence. Base64 is as secure as keeping your housedoor locked and keeping the key in front of it, on the outside.

Comment: Thats not correct. You can add salt to base64 to make it more secured. If you go through the link i have given, maybe you will understand what i am talking. No offence, i accept what you say, but it completely depends on user till what level the user wants the encryption to be secured.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha: ***BASE64 IS NOT ENCRYPTION!*** This is actually ***dangerous*** that you think it is.

Comment: @bobby - yes i agree to what you say. i shouldn't have used the term "Security" in my answer. Trust me, this discussion was worth. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Salt to base64? :) Don't be joking. Base64 is a reversible transformation, not encryption. There is no sense in adding salt.