# How do I add PHP and HTML div code inside a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem with JavaScript and PHP code. The following is my code:

```
<div class= "stars" data-id="'.$rows[$id].'" data-title="name "></div>
```

When I put this code into HTML, the script working. But when I put this code into JavaScript, this code doesn't work. I modified this code to put it in JavaScript:

```
<?php echo "<div class= \'stars\' data-id=\'".$rows[$id]."\' data-title= \'name \' ></div>" ;?>
```

Anyway, this code doesn't work. Did I miss anything?

```
var script_data= [
    {
        content:'<?php echo $rows[$name];?> <?php echo "<div class= \'stars\' data-id=\'".$rows[$id]."\' data-title= \'name \' ></div>" ;?>'  
    }
];
```

Comment: did you make sure that the javascript file has a php extension? If not, the php code will never get interpreted. Also refer to this question, it's just a google search away: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-files Also to note, this is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Was you first code (in html) in a php echo statement? Please provide the rest of the code.
Regarding your 2nd attempt: can you describe in detail what "not working" means? Do you have output? If so, what's the result? I assume that you put this code in a php file and not in a JS file?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language while Javascript is a client side language. If you're inserting php code into a web page with Javascript you're going to see the php code itself, and not the data that the php code would output. You will probably want to read up on AJAX which will allow you to post and receive data from php scripts with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
#for test:
<?php $rows['lol'] = 'rofl';$name = 'lol'; $id="lol";$title = 'lol';?>

#code below works with PHP Version 5.4.39
<script>
var script_data= [
    {
<?php echo "title: '$rows[$title]' , \n";
  echo "content:' $rows[$name] <div class= \'stars\' data-id=\'".$rows[$id]."\' data-title= \'name \' ></div>'"; ?>

    }
];
```

Comment: The problem is: the **class** is not active in this functional (it's very strange), and really is a problem that should not be, everything works well outside de class , the class it's very important