# Using PHP in .JS file?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

So I'm trying to use PHP in a .js file, here's what I have so far.

**.htaccess** (any *.api.js will be processed as PHP)

```
<FilesMatch "^.*?api.*?$">
SetHandler php54-script
</FilesMatch>
```

**map.api.js**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
//my php here
?>

//my javascript here
```

**.php files all include**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="map.api.js"></script>
```

For some reason this isn't working, and after much research I can't find a solution.

In the chrome developer tools I get an error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` - pretty self explanatory, it isn't expecting `<?php` at the top of the `map.api.js` file.

Anyone else here tried using PHP in a .js file before? If there is a better solution I'd like to know as I can't find much on Google.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-files

Comment: I am trying to avoid putting 1000+ lines of javascript at the top of my HTML file, so I'd like to know if there is a solution to the way I'm trying to do this.

Comment: Your regex seems bad. 
Try `\bapi\b` instead of `^.*?api.*?$`;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an file with php extension and include it in your website as javascript.

**map.api.js**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
//my php here
?>
//my javascript here
```

**In your HTML File:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="map.api.php"></script>
```

If you wan't to hide the php extension, you can work with mod_rewrite (Apache):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^map.api.js$ map.api.php
```

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting the  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error after renaming `map.api.js` to `map.api.php` (and updating it in my html/php files)

Comment: I removed PHP handlers from the .htaccess file and it now works, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to set PHP as handler for your `.api.js` files. You can use `.php` files as scripts too, as long as you preserve your `Content-Type` header.

So your file would be something like:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/javasctipt);
    // code...
?>

alert("This is JS");
```

And in your HTML page you can include it like this:

```
<script src="/map.api.php"></script>
```

This is also useful if you want to manipulate the JS code using PHP before sending it to the client, so you can do something like this:

```
<script src="/map.api.php?feature=1"></script>
```

and in your PHP:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/javasctipt);
?>

alert("This is JS");

<?php
    if ($_GET["feature"] == "1") {
        echo "alert('Cool feature imported');";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Removed the PHP handlers from .htaccess and used Take's solution. Now it works, thanks Marco!

Answer (score 1):

Take's response is the best practice.

If you really want executing PHP code inside dotJS files.

**.htaccess**

```
<FilesMatch "\bapi\b">
SetHandler php54-script
</FilesMatch>
```

And be sure you allow .htaccess in your Apache config:

```
<Directory /your/path>
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Satisfy all
</Directory>
```