# Wordpress php: hide "echo do_shortcode" string when javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, echo, shortcode

I wonder how to hide shortcode in wordpress when javascript is disabled.
The shortcode appear like strings so is ti a way to hide them with some codes?

here an exemple in php when i call a shordtcode:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[SHORTCODE HERE]'); ?>
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

for this issue you can use `<noscript>` tag. So f.e:

```
<noscript>
 <p>JS is switched off in a browser</p>
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
...put here js code, which will be executed if js will be enabled...
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that i can't put a php tag in script tag.

Comment: you can see how you can do that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-files