# Embed PHP script output in javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

file1.php will echo the URL of the WordPress post featured image.
I am trying to embed this URL in img tag in the **file2.js** file.

**file1.php**

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
<?php echo $url ?>
```

**file2.js**

```
var mjvfiurl;
$.get("/wp-content/plugins/mjv_sample_plugin/file1.php", function(mjvdata) {
     mjvfiurl=mjvdata;
});

var fapDom = '<div id="fap-wrapper"><img src="'+mjvfiurl+'" alt="" /></div>';

$('body').append(fapDom);
```

But its not working. Source code rendered as below:

```
<img src="undefined" alt="">
```

Console error:

```
http://padals.com/baahubali-beginning/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

Just to embed the PHP output in the javascript image tag. Exact answer is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Patrick - Sorry I don't think it a duplicate of what you have given.

Comment: It is a duplicate because your problem is you are using an asynchronous method but are not waiting till it has finished before trying to use the data, which is covered in the linked duplicate

Comment: Check the issues solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-files

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery's $.get(), what you're looking for is:

```
$.get("/wp-content/plugins/mjv_sample_plugin/file1.php", function(mjvdata) {
     var mjvfiurl = mjvdata;
     var fapDom = '<div id="fap-wrapper"><img src="'+mjvfiurl+'" alt="" /></div>';
    $('body').append(fapDom);
});
```

Your problem is that since you're doing an asynchronous call, `mjvfiurl` might not be defined by the time you append to the body because the request sent out to get the URL hasn't finished yet.

When you make async calls, the rest of the JavaScript will execute.

Comment: I up voted @Patrick's comment because the accepted answer from that post goes into better detail the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming as well as giving examples on how to solve your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    phpVars = new Array();
    <?php foreach($vars as $var) {
        echo 'phpVars.push("' . $var . '");';
    };
    ?>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourScriptThatUsesPHPVars.js"></script>
```

If you just need to pass variables from PHP to the javascript, you can have a tag in the php/html file using the javascript to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to call functions, then you can do this like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    functionOne(<?php echo implode(', ', $arrayWithVars); ?>);
    functionTwo(<?php echo $moreVars; ?>, <?php echo $evenMoreVars; ?>);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="YourFunctions.js"></script>
```