# JavaScript with php variabe isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new to to working with php html and javascript so I apologize if this question is bad but whenever I add this variable that echos php I can no longer advance the program to the next window. The only thing I can think of is that the next window is a html and not a php file. Would that be the reason or am I doing something else wrong? Thanks!

```
<script>
    var winner = <?php echo $winnerName ?>;
    //Creates random num for winner base on num of members.
    function changeNum() {
        //Num of members.
        num = document.getElementById("num").value;
        //winner.
        num2 = Math.round((Math.random() * (num - 1) + 1));
        //Storage to second page
        localStorage.setItem("winner", num2);
        localStorage.setItem("name", winner);

        window.location = "second_page.html";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try this var winner = '<?php echo $winnerName ?>';

Comment: What is the value of  `$winnerName`? If it's a string (which it looks like it is) you'll need to wrap it in quotes: `'<? echo $winnerName;?>'`  -also, side note, you can also skip the `echo` and just do `<?=$winnerName;?>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include PHP inside JavaScript (.js) files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-files)

Comment: Thanks Ben D and user3510665 and YakovL I dont think it's a duplicate since I'm not using .js just have a javascript in a .php file dont think I said that anywhere, sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple of potential issues:

1. `$winnerName` is probably a string, which means that you need to wrap it in quotes: `'<?=$winnerName;?>'` (and probably escape it as well to be on the safe side):  `'<?=addslashes($winnerName);?>'`
2. Make sure that `num` is a legitimate integer: `parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value)` just in case that might be throwing an error.

Also, you'll want to look at your console to see what javascript error is being throw - it will narrow down the issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will print out your string in plain text and to the browser it will exactly like if you were to have typed and hardcoded the string held by `$winnerName` in the file itself.

For example if `$winnerName = 'Bob'` the browser will see `var winner = Bob;` and complain that you haven't defined the variable `Bob`.

Keeping that in mind, there are two methods to make javascript treat your string as a string, and not a variable.

1. `var winner = <?php print json_decode($winnerName); ?>;`
2. `var winner = '<?php print $winnerName; ?>'`

Both of which will display to the browser `var winner = 'Bob'`.

Comment: N.B. you should pretty much never use the 2nd way. It's dangerous. A quote will break it, and backslashes will mess with it.