# How do I loop through a JSON array with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Firstly here's the code I'm trying, I want to check this JSON once per second and append each new message individually instead of refreshing the entire HTML.

```
$.getJSON("alpha.json", function(json) {
    $.each(json,function(i, value){
       if (value.info.user == "<?php echo $user; ?>") {
          $("#messages").append("<div class='message sent'><p>" + value.message + "</p></div>");
       } else {
          $("#messages").append("<div class='message from'><p>" + value.message + "</p></div>");
       }
    });
});
```

The JSON structure is

```
[
 {"info": {"user":"username"},"message":"1"},
 {"info": {"user":"username2"},"message":"2"},
 {"info": {"user":"username"},"message":"3"}
]
```

I'm trying to loop through like you can in `PHP` but it's not showing anything? If I remove the if statement it shows all the messages but that's not ideal because it needs the styling.

Assuming my `$user` is "username" the above `json` would show this HTML

```
<div id="messages">
  <div class="message sent">
     <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message from">
     <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message sent">
     <p>3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:  needed to be surrounded by quotes now messages show.

Comment: You have a PHP fragment in your js code `echo $user`, assuming $user is a string, it has to be quoted `value.info.user == '<?php echo $user; ?>'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-files. Note, I have not marked it as duplicate as I'm not sure if you can access PHP code in JS file.

Comment: Btw this code is in a PHP file. On a side not this isn't a duplicate. It's a specific example of me trying to use $.getJSON to loop through JSON.

Comment: @DaltonEdwards the way I see it, you already know how to loop through a json array. You should re-frame your question title.

Comment: This answer isn't answered all the way yet. I'm trying to append new messages.

Comment: If your php file and alpha.json located in same path, then there is no issue with your code. It's working fine for me.