# Can't call PHP function from JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to run a PHP function within a JS Block in an HTML document.
The function includes PHP, HTML and JS.

The function includes a loop that runs just fine until the last time, where it instead prints out this:

**"; document.getElementById("code").innerHTML += sayThis;**

The error message says: 
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

The function is called load_offers, and it retrieves data from a database, and displays it in list objects.

It does what it's supposed to until I add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sayThis = "<?php load_offers(); ?>";
document.getElementById("code").innerHTML += sayThis;
</script>
```

The function needs to be called so it loads 6 more list objects when the user had scrolled down to the end of the page instead of loading everything at once. This is why I need JS to call the function.

Here is the function:

```
    function load_offers(){
//Gets variables needed to connect to mysql.
    global $servername;
    global $username;
    global $password;
    global $dbname;
    global $fetched;
    global $amount;

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Creates a query that loads a limited number of offers.
     $query = "SELECT ID, TITLE, IMAGELINK, DATE_ADDED, OLD_PRICE, NEW_PRICE, SAVE_PERCENT FROM erbjudanden WHERE APPROVED = 'Y' ORDER BY DATE_ADDED DESC 
    LIMIT $fetched, $amount";

    $result = $conn->query($query);

//Declares arrays.
    $all_offers = array();
    $titles = array();
    $imagelinks = array();
    $dates = array();
    $old_prices = array();
    $new_prices = array();
    $percents = array();
    $link = array();
    $i = 0;
    $bad_chars = array("'", "!", ",", "\"", "(", ")", "[", "]", "#", "&", "+", "=", "@", "$", "%", "|" );

//Gets data from row into arrays.
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $all_offers[$i] = $row['ID'];
        $titles[$i] = $row['TITLE'];
        $imagelinks[$i] = $row['IMAGELINK'];
        $dates[$i] = $row['DATE_ADDED'];
        $old_prices[$i] = $row['OLD_PRICE'];
        $new_prices[$i] = $row['NEW_PRICE'];
        $percents[$i] = $row['SAVE_PERCENT'];

//Creates a link with only numbers, lowercase letters and - instead of spaces.
        $link[$i] = $row['TITLE'];
        $link[$i] = strtolower($link[$i]);
        $link[$i] = str_replace(" ", "-", $link[$i]);
    foreach($bad_chars as $bad){
    $link[$i] = str_replace($bad, "", $link[$i]);
    }
    $link[$i] = str_replace("--", "-", $link[$i]);
    $link[$i] = $link[$i] . "-" . $all_offers[$i];
        $i++;

       }


//Writes out data as listobjects.
    $a = 0;
    foreach ($all_offers as $offer)
    {
    $aID = $fetched + $a;
    echo'<a href="'.$link[$a].'">
            <li class = "listobjekt">
            <h4  align = "center" >' . $titles[$a] . '</h4>
            <img src="' . $imagelinks[$a] . '" class = "tellme" id = "tiny'. $aID .'">
            <table class = "pri">
            <tr><td width="50">Förr:</td><td id ="for"> ' . $old_prices[$a] . ' :-</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Nu:</td><td id = "bu">' . $new_prices[$a] . ' :-</td></tr>
            <tr><td >Spara:</td><td id = "spara">' . $percents[$a] . ' %</td></tr>
            </table>
            </li></a>

//Makes image fit it's container and align correctly.

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var file = document.getElementById("tiny'.$aID.'");

    if(file.height < file.width){

    file.style.width="180px";
    padding = file.width - file.height;
    padding = padding / 2;
    padding = padding+"px";
    file.style.marginTop=padding;
    file.style.marginBottom=padding;

    }
    else{
    file.style.height="180px";

    padding = file.height - file.width;
    padding = padding / 2;
    padding = padding+"px";
    file.style.marginLeft=padding;
    file.style.marginRight=padding;
    }
    </script>
    ';


    $a++;
    }
    }
```

Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: By does not print anything do you mean you get a blank white screen? Or just that element doesn't get the text? If the former then you have a PHP error some where and will need to check your server logs or turn on `display_errors`

Comment: @Phill, I have it in a .js file. I link it to the html file like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scroll.js"></script>, I have also tried to do it in html within a <script> block.

Comment: note php does not parse js files by default

Comment: I don't get your point. Why are you ´echo´ a string when you can directly give the value.

Comment: @Patrick Evans Nothing changes from the way the document looked before. Whether the script is there or not doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Why don't you try `echo 'hello'` instead of `"echo 'hello'"`

Comment: @Phill, I checked the page source and the code element was still empty.

Comment: @Patrick Evans How do you make it parse then?

Comment: @B.Tibell  Your Question is answered here . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-files

Comment: PHP can render html file but not js file.

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry, it works now when it's within a <script> block. But is it possible to make it work in an external .js file?

Comment: Here's the problem(although I'm not sure if an external file will solve it):

Comment: *Continuation XD* I want to call a PHP function which includes html and php and js. There are both " and ', so it won't work when I call it within a script block. The error message speaks of a unterminated string or an unexpected identifier. The function includes a loop, and it does run correctly until the last time where it instead prints out some js code. I'm sorry that this sounds so confusing...

Comment: I strongly suggest you create a new question (and delete this one) since it has fundamentally changed from the original

Comment: @B.Tibell I've re-opened your question but you need to seriously put some work into explaining the problem. Show examples of the `load_offers()` output. Explain what you'd like to happen vs what is actually happening. Show any error messages **as text**. Nobody wants to try and read code / messages from an image. Good luck. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @B.Tibell spend a lot of time on your question, making it super clear. In doing so, there's a good chance you'll solve it yourself. See https://rubberduckdebugging.com/

Comment: @Phil, Edited questton

Comment: Why are you wanting to us JS for this? What's wrong with `<div id="code"><?= load_offers() ?></div>`?

Comment: @Phil I need to use javascript to first detect user scroll and then when the user reach the bottom of the page it needs to call load_offers so that i can load more offers otherwise i would need to load everything at once. Anyway, i have solved my probelm, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use PHP to adjust your images.

Secondly, make sure that the javascript variable sayThis is on one line. Javascript don't support multilines with singe quotes.

I tested this on your computer and it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

## It may be simpler to run your JS in the PHP document

In order to hypothetically work, it would have to be in the document body between script tags.

Note: I tested this on my machine and it works. The file extension was .php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var test = "<?php echo 'test'; ?>";
  console.log(test);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Apparently this isn't the best practice, it may be better to run your PHP like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var test = <?= json_encode('test') ?>;
  console.log(test);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Props to Phil in the comments for helping me work this out.

Comment: Safest method for including PHP output into JS is `var test = <?= json_encode('test') ?>`

Comment: Interesting, I'd like to know more. Please elaborate!

Comment: `json_encode()` will encode the output correctly for JSON which just happens to be exactly what is required for inclusion in JavaScript. It also means you don't have to worry about quotes around or within the output.

Comment: Also, you **can** run PHP inside a JS file, it's just not common ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/9138781/283366

Comment: Would it be possible to do it in the manner that the OP is referencing his JS though?

Comment: Yes. The file extension of the requested resource doesn't really matter. You would just need to configure your web server to run the files through the PHP interpreter (via module, FPM, etc). See the answer I linked directly

Comment: Gotchya, I'll have a good read. Super appreciate your comments

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer to be less prescriptive. +1