# double quotes is not allowed in jquery formbuilder

Tags: jquery, formbuilder

I am using jquery formbuilder. I am getting formbuilder json data to database. After in edit formbuilder i am taking formbuilder data as below:

```
var options = {

    formData: '<?php echo str_replace("'","\'",$forms[0]['form_template']);?>',
    disableFields: ['autocomplete'],
    editOnAdd: true
  };

  $(fbTemplate).formBuilder(options);
});
```

In edit page $forms[0]['form_template'] is json data of formbuilder. It is working Now. But if we are add in place of form lable as forexample formlable as "Test" then save. Them it is not display in edit page. Please help me. i am using form-builder.js.

Comment: `<?php ... ?>` means there's a block of (server-side) PHP code. If that code has reached the browser (it shouldn't) I suggest you double-check that your server is properly configured to execute PHP.

Comment: Yes, It is executing properly when we are not using double quotes in place of lable name. And it is working with single quotes. For example paragraph as test'paragraph', then saved. Then it is displaying in edit page.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var options = {
    formData: '<?php echo str_replace("\'","\'",$forms[0][\'form_template\']);?>',
    disableFields: ['autocomplete'],
    editOnAdd: true
};
```

Comment: In js file [\'form_template\'] it is not supporting.

Comment: then use '<?php echo str_replace("\'","\'",$forms[0]["form_template"]);?>' as you are not using any double quote in it

Comment: If it is in a js file, you cannot use php in it, look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-files, it may help you