# How can I access Laravel Helper from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, helper

I have a Laravel web app and want to access my Laravel Helper from any .js file.

In normally I accessed helper from script in blade.php file like this:-

```
<script>
function getSiteSettings() {
    return JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode(Helper::getSettings()) ?>');
}
</script>
```

But I want to access this from my *script.js* file. **Is it possible?**
I have tried with localStorage and get it very easily but problem is, in site settings have some secured data.

And if possible to **hide localStorage data** then my problem will be solved.

Comment: In .js file, you can not use php code. If you want to get  data through js use ajax

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241422/include-php-inside-javascript-js-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. Basically, there is no direct way to write PHP code in the `.js` file. Here is 3 short way to get PHP/Laravel variable or Laravel Helper.

Solution 1. Call an ajax and get the return the value from js and use it as needed.

```
$(function() {
     // ajax call
});
```

Solution 2. Any Laravel Helper/Var can be accessible from a blade file, like this:

```
<script>
    let name = "{{ \Helper::get_name() }}";
</script>
```

and use this name anywhere in js.

***Solution 3***. The last and best way which I have been using is:
Add the external script in the blade and add a getter and setter method into the script so that you can set the value from the blade file inside the js.

```
// in external/script.js script
var GetLaravelHelper = function () {
    let options = {
        name_from_laravel : ''
    }

    return {
        init: function(){
            // code for on load
        },
        set_options: function(data){
            Object.assign( options, data );
        },
        get_options: function(){
            return options;
        }
    }
}();

window.GetLaravelHelper = GetLaravelHelper; // You can get acces this GetLaravelHelper into balde file where you imort this js

document.onload(function(){
    GetLaravelHelper.init();
})
```

Then in blade, you can set any value into the Object like this:

```
<script src="external/script.js"></script>
<script>
   GetLaravelHelper.set_options({
        name_from_laravel: "{{ config('app.name') }}", // or anything from laravel/php
   })
</script>
```

Hope it will help you a lot. Happy Coding <3

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to do what you're doing right now.

Or, Create a resource endpoint that can return JSON of these settings on page load in your `script.js` file:

```
// script.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     // make an ajax request here and load your setting in a js variable
});

// if using jquery
$(function() {
     // make an $.ajax request here and load your setting in a js 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be call an api using Ajax or Axios(is using vue) inside the getSiteSettings function and in the response of the api you return the data.